# PyCharm file status highlight change color blue even after git push. This is done after line separator

Tags: git, pycharm, ide, jetbrains-ide

Pycharm file status changed color to blue after git commit and git push. Normally the files change back to normal (like to changes).

Moved from windows to WSL (Unix),

hence all files separators needed to be updated.

[instructions from PyCharm line separator](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-line-endings-and-line-separators.html)

after updating PyCharm, git status showed all filed not staged, so i did

> git add . git commit -m "bla la" and   git push

and after git push, PyCharm file status changed blue, like there are some changes somewhere.

git status remains "your branch is up to date"

but now it's hard to track changes, since all  files status are now blue meaning all files have been changed.

anyone with an idea of what's going on?

Comment: Try commiting all files once